# How to group daily data by month

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Have a somewhat unusual Excel question:

I have a column of data that only has values of -1, 1, or 0:

```
| X |
| 1 |
| 0 |
|-1 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
```

I also have daily dates associated with each row, i.e. `2/1/2013`.

What I would like to do, is to have an easy way to view how many `1`s, `0`s, or `-1`s in total are associated with each month of data. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Pivot Table to [group your data by dates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/group-items-in-a-pivottable-report-HP010175903.aspx#BMgroup_dates_or_times).

**Steps**

Assuming your raw data looks something like this:

[image: raw data]

Highlight all of the data and on the `Insert` tab select `PivotTable`. From the `PivotTable Field List` on the right select the `Date` and `X` fields. In the `Values` box in the lower right select the `Sum of X` dropdown and choose `Value Field Settings` change to summarize by `Count`.

You should now have something like:

[image]

Now up on the ribbon select the `Options` tab in the `PivotTable Tools` section. 
Select `Group Selection` in the `Group` section.

[image]

Now choose months in the dialog

[image]

And your data should look like

[image]

Comment: this is perfect, ty